# Guardar sin repetir imagen en carpeta local

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy modificando un código para que cuando guarde las imágenes en la carpeta local no guarde el mismo nombre, si se guarda la misma foto, sino se renombre, pero no me funciona: sigue guardando normal mas no se repite la foto si es la misma.

```html
<form method="post" action="upload-photo.php>" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<label>Agregar las fotos al nuevo album:</label><br>
<input type="file" name="photo" /><button type='submit' name="submit" value="up" class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-success'>Cargar </button>
 </form>
```

El archivo *uploah-photo.php*

```php
include 'conexion.php';

//Este en el if para que cambie o renombre las fotos
if (file_exists('url')){
    // Rename
    $_FILES['photo']['name'] .= '_'.substr(sha1(rand(1,999)),0,-30);
    }
// end
if ($_FILES['photo']['name'] != null) {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], "imagenes/". $_FILES['photo']['name']);
    $ruta = "imagenes/". $_FILES['photo']['name'];

    $upload_photo = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO gallery_photos (ruta) VALUES ('$ruta')");
    if ($upload_photo) {
        echo 'guardado';
    } else {
        echo $mysqli->error;
    }
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
```

Comment: file_exists('url')???? no sera file_exists($_FILES['photo']['name'])????

Comment: Nop (file_exists(['photo']['name'])  Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestiondeinventario\upload-photo.php on line 5
guardado .. guarda la foto pero no cumple su funcion

Comment: No entiendo, quieres subir la misma imagen con diferente nombre o quieres remplazar la imagen? Porque si quieres guardar la misma imagen con diferente nombre, para que estas preguntando si ya existe dicha imagen?? Solo cambias el nombre, la subes y listo...

Comment: la imagen se sube automaticamente con ruta a la BD y se guarda en una carpeta local, de la cual el usuario no va tener acceso ni yo estare cambiando nombre de imagenes ya que eso va a un servidor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que necesitas es renombrar para evitar duplicados pueda que sirva lo siguiente.

Cuando hice un sistema de RRHH que tenia muchos archivos e imágenes de muchos empleados (+1000) renombraba cada archivo antes de subirlo a la DB con el siguiente script

```
<?php
    // Insertando imagen a un empleado
    $empID = $_POST['envio_de_form']; // Este es el ID de mi registro en la DB
    # definimos o creamos la carpeta destino para las Imagene por ID de empleado
    $carpetaDestinoImagen = "archivos/docs/".$empID."/";
    @mkdir($carpetaDestinoImagen);
    # si hay algun archivo que subir en el envio del POST
    if($_FILES["imagen"]["name"][0]){
        # recorremos todos los arhivos que se han subido
        for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["imagen"]["name"]);$i++){
            # si exsite la carpeta o se ha creado
            if(file_exists($carpetaDestinoImagen) || @mkdir($carpetaDestinoImagen)){
                $extension = explode(".",$_FILES["imagen"]["name"][$i]);
                $origenImagen= $_FILES["imagen"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                $nameImagen = $_FILES["imagen"]["name"][$i];
                // Acá cambio el nombre y genero un hash único con dos diferentes métodos
                $urlImagen= $carpetaDestinoImagen.sha1(uniqid($nameImagen)).".".$extension[1];

                echo 'Origen >> '.$origenImagen.'<br>';
                echo 'URL >> '.$urlImagen.'<br>';
                echo 'Nombre >> '.$nameImagen.'<br>';
                echo 'Extension >> '.$extension[1].'<br>';

                /*
                   En base a las variables anteriores,
                   (pueden ser más, dependiendo de la información que tu necesites)
                   haces el insert en tu Base de Datos,
                   el insert de la url ($urlImagen) obviamente.
                */

                # movemos el archivo
                if(@move_uploaded_file($origenImagen, $urlImagen)){
                    echo 'Imagen <b>'.$nameImagen.'</b> Movida Correctamente con ruta <b>'.$urlImagen.'</b><br>';

                }
                else{ // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
                    echo 'Error al Subir Imagen<br>'; // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
                } // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
            }
            else{ // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
                echo 'Error en Carpeta Imagen<br>'; // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
            } // esto lo puedes comentar cuando ya te funciones todo
        }
    }
```

Comment: Exactamente busco esto que los archivos de imagen se renombren para evitar duplicados.

Comment: Bien @Noveember, pero un consejo útil para toda la vida. Aprende a ser claro en tus peticiones/dudas/preguntas. Vas a recibir respuestas más claras y rápidas, por ejemplo, quise responder a esto ayer mismo, pero ya me ha pasado que respondo y luego el OP sale que no quiere eso, sino algo "más simple". La cosa es; entre mejor y más clara sea tu pregunta, así será la respuesta :-)