# No se suben archivos mediante función PHP

Tags: php, html, xampp

Estoy intentando subir una imagen mediante PHP. la imagen no se carga en la carpeta especificada y sale error de que no se ha enviado. Estoy trabajando con XAMPP dentro de la carpeta htdocs. dentro de esta tengo el archivo php y una carpeta llamada pdf_files.

estoy trabajando en una MAC y todo el resto del código de la pagina funciona sin problema excepto esto.

```
**archivo pdfindex.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre Archivo">
        <input type="text" name="descripcion" placeholder="Descripcion">
        <input type="file" name="archivo"><br><br>
        <input type="submit" name="subir" value="enviar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>

**archivo upload.php
<?php 

include 'con.php';
if($_POST['subir']){
    // var_dump($_FILES['archivo']);
    if(file_exists($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'])){
        // echo "se ha subido";
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], 'pdf_files/' .$_FILES['archivo']['name'])){
            echo "exito";
        }else{
            echo "no se subio";
        }

    }else{
        echo "no se ha subido";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Verificar: (1) Que exista la ruta de destino del archivo. (2) Que el usuario de Apache tenga permisos para escribir el directorio donde se guardarán los archivos. (3) Que el archivo no sea más grande que `post_max_size` y `upload_max_filesize` en **php.ini**. Si es necesario, modificar esos valores y reiniciar Apache.

Comment: Verifica el código de error, colocando algo como (esto sustituye tu `if` con un ternario): **`$msg=move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'], 'pdf_files/' .$_FILES['archivo']['name']) ? "Archivo subido" : "Error: ".$_FILES["archivo"]["error"]; echo $msg;`** Dinos qué muestra el mensaje. Para saber la causa del error, [revisa aquí los código de error](https://www.php.net/manual/es/features.file-upload.errors.php). Como bien dice @aeportugal, debes controlar posibles errores, como permisos, que no exceda los máximos permitidos, etc. Todos esos controles faltan en tu código.

Comment: Y, puede que falten controles más delicados, los cuales espero tengas restringidos de otro modo. Por ejemplo, ¿qué tal si te suben un script `.php` malicioso en esa carpeta para luego hacer algo como `www.tusitio.com/pdf_files/esteScriptHaraUnDesastreEnTuServidor.php`. Me pregunto si estás bloqueando de algún modo la subida de archivos con ciertas extensiones o más bien si tienes una lista blanca de extensiones de archivos que está permitido subir ¿?

Comment: Mira si [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/600896/guardar-sin-repetir-imagen-en-carpeta-local/600971#600971) te da una luz sobre como subir archivos...